# Android app kills on kindle fire when losing focus

Tags: android, focus, kindle

An app that I have made works great on any regular android device, but when the app loses focus on the Kindle Fire it kills. Does anyone have any idea as to why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once your app is no longer in the foreground, its process can be terminated at any time by the OS to free up memory for other processes. This happens on every Android device. It is possible that some versions of the Kindle Fire may be more aggressive about it, but having your process be terminated is standard behavior and something your app needs to account for.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with CommonsWare just to add to that point please check if in onPause ur manually finishing your activity or not sometimes that can be reason ,I know it sounds silly but people make silly mistakes sometimes :)